# Apache POI cannot recognize sheet name: Specified named range 'RtSummary.1' does not exist in the current workbook

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am generating Excel file by java. I need to reference "summary" sheet in "overview" sheet. First, I declare the summary sheet name as "RtSummary.1-PLAN1". Then I worked on cells in overview sheet. However, I got error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParseException: Specified named range 'RtSummary.1' does not exist in the current workbook.
```

I print out the sheet name. It prints exactly what I expect. (It prints **"RtSummary.1-PLAN1"** instead of **"RtSummary.1"**). 
Then I tried to change the sheet name from "RtSummary.1-PLAN1" to "test". I didn't get such error any more.

I am confused what's wrong with my sheet name to cause such error. My code is as below:

```
    //cell 3 (total orders) will be filled later
    String summarySheetName="RtSummary."+snapshots[i].trim()+Integer.toString(i+1);
    String detailSheetName="RtDetail."+snapshots[i]+(i+1);
    Row orderRow;


    //first comparison table content
    int rowOffset=15+snapshots.length;
    curRow=overviewSheet.createRow(rowOffset+i);
    orderRow=curRow;
    curCell=curRow.createCell(1);
    curCell.setCellStyle(lrBarStyle);
    curCell.setCellValue(snapshots[i]);

    curCell=curRow.createCell(2);
    curCell.setCellStyle(lrBarStyle);
    if(sameDay)
        curCell.setCellValue(dateSDF.format(startDate.getTime()));
    else
        curCell.setCellValue(dateSDF.format(startDate.getTime())+"-"+dateSDF.format(endDate.getTime()));

    curCell=curRow.createCell(4);
    curCell.setCellStyle(lrBarStyle);
    System.out.println(summarySheetName);
    curCell.setCellFormula(summarySheetName+"!N"+(routes.length+2));
    System.out.println("0k");
```

Comment: The sheet name contains characters (the `-`) which leads to the need putting the sheet name in single quotes in references: `curCell.setCellFormula("'"+summarySheetName+"'!N"+(routes.length+2));`

Comment: You are right. I already resolved it by adding the quote sign.